# Dunder or magic method to return the type() of the object

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are dunder or magic functions for many things like to get `len(), print()` we can even use `help()` without even using a magic function and use `?Class` if we have used the proper docstring.

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
    
    def __repr__(self):
        pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        pass
    
    def __len__(self):
        pass
        
node = Node([1,2,3])
type(node)
```

When I used the `type()`, it said `__main__Node`. What magic method I have to use it to return something like `LinkedList.Node` or simple `Node`?? Just like it returns `list`, `str` or `numpy.ndarray`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type()` does not call any magic method. It merely returns the value of `instance.__class__` attribute.

Manually overwriting it is not necessarily a good idea. If you want `LinkedList.Node` instead of `__main__Node` the best thing to do is to define `Node` inside a `LinkedList` module.